# How can an MSI installer extension locate the installation directory of another application?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a main application `TheApp` which supports plugins. Application A is installed by default at `$(ProgramFiles)\TheApp`, but the gold-owners want this to be user-customizable, so its location may vary depending on user input at installation time.

Plugins are installed by copying them to a subdirectory `Packages` under installation directory. Specifically, no registry settings need to be set for a package to load, and I'm trying to stay out of the registry as much as possible. Naturally, if the user changed the installation directory when installing `TheApp`, the plugins must also change their installation location to match.

How is this best accomplished? I'm not seasoned at writing MSI installers with WiX, but my first attempt would probably be to create a registry key when `TheApp` is installed saving its install location, and then have the plugins search for the registry key. This forces me to create registry value, which is what I'm trying to avoid if possible. However, it strikes me that the installer should be able to take advantage of the Windows Installer database to locate the `TheApp`'s installation directory. That would remove the need for a registry entry.

Is there a "best practice" for how to do this inter-installer communication, specifically the installation directory? How would the communication look like, given that both installers will be written in WiX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Windows Installer database and, under certain conditions, without a custom action!

The standard tables and actions support searching for installed components. So, if your app directory has a certain component installed in it (e.g, your app .exe) that you give a fixed GUID, your plugin installer can find it.

Since you'll need the "MainComponentGuid" in all projects, extract it out as a `define` in an `Include` file.

Plugin authoring:

```
<?include ../MainSetup/MainComponentGuid.wxi?>

<Property Id="MAINDIR">
  <ComponentSearch Id="MainComponentSearch" Type="file" Guid="$(var.MainComponentGuid)">
    <DirectorySearch Id="MainComponentDirectorySearch" AssignToProperty="yes"  Depth="0" />
  </ComponentSearch>
</Property>

<CustomAction Id="SetInstallFolder" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[MAINDIR]" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetInstallFolder" After="CostFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

In your Directory structure, you'd make `Packages` a child of `INSTALLFOLDER`.  You might also use `MAINDIR` in a `LaunchCondition` to prevent installing a plugin unless the main product is installed.

Comment: Thanks Tom: this was the information I was looking for. I especially appreciate the sample code. It gives me a good starting point for my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a registry key during installation and then finding it is quite [simple using WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/files_and_registry_toc.htm).

You can use the following to create a key:

```
<Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU"
                 Key="Software\MyApplicationName"
          Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
     <RegistryValue Action="write"  Name="InstallDir" Type="string" Value="[INSTALLDIR]"  />
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

Here `InstallDir` is a WIX property where the user selected target path of your software is set. Once you have this key setup then you can look for this in your plugins installer (assuming there is a separate installer for plugins) by using the following example:

```
<Property Id="AnyNameYouLike">
<RegistrySearch Id="YourRegistrySearchId"
                Root="HKCU"
                Key="Software\MyApplicationName"
                Name="InstallDir"
                Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

This code will set the value of property `AnyNameYouLike` to the path stored in `InstallDir`. You can put this code somewhere before you intend to use the path.

Alternatively, you can create a file in windows `ProgramData\YourApp` or in `Users` folder to store the install location if you really really want to avoid doing registry stuff.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check, if your main product writes InstallLocation key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

2) If there is no such key, set [ARPINSTALLLOCATION property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

3) If the key was written by main product - just read this value with RegistryLocator and set TARGETDIR.

Comment: Good idea to use a registry entry that is already part of the installer. But this would require knowing the main product's ProductCode at the time the plugin installer is written. It could change from version to version so an older plugin wouldn't be able to find a newer version of the main program.

Comment: Well, you have to know at least UpgradeCode of the main product. Because you have to check, if the main product alrerady installed :) If so, you could get ProductCode via UpgradeTable and UseReleatedProducts action. So, you'll be able to format correct registry path.